\StageDir immediatlely after \DramPer in dramatist (Tex question)
is there a way to put a \StageDir command following \DramPer on the page? So that i can put another \StageDir under a scene or an act.
Thank You
Gian Paolo
here is the possible code

and here the expected result


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Please also make sure to add the code as text and not as image so we can copy it to reproduce your problem.

And please not, that a screenshot may be helpful, but it never can supersede a minimal working example added as block code, because we cannot copy&paste a screenshot to test the code, modify it, test it again and show the result.

Sorry, you're right. Here is a minimal example of the code:
https://pastebin.com/X2X13xGn

Sorry, you're right. Here is a minimal example of the code: pastebin.com/X2X13xGn
